# how to attach a listener with parameters to an element even if it is not yet loaded

Tags: jquery

how to attach a listener with parameters to an element ('.datepicker') even if it is not yet loaded ?

this is my code. It is executed when a **text input** is **focused**.

```
$('body .datepicker').datetimepicker({
     timepicker: false,
     format: 'Y-m-d',
     formatDate: 'Y-m-d'
});
```

I do not find how to do it with the "on" method.

Thanks!

Comment: Which method, a listener? Something like `on('click',...` ? And what kind of parameters you need to pass in this method?

Comment: Everything is specified in my code above

Comment: Are you talking about [this](https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/#onChangeDateTime) example where you use a callback function that gets called when the input has changed? Please [edit] the question and include a [mcve] of that are you trying to achieve - Nothing is specified in your code above and the question is unclear

Comment: no, it's not decently specified in your code above... above you are instantiating a datepicker object with some properties in the `.datepicker` element, and in the description you are talking about method with `on` (which usually is a listener), please, be more specific if you want a decent answer. Help to be helped.

Comment: ok, we are making progress, it is a listener, but now: which kind of listener, click, blur, change? What is the expected behavior? Is this `datetimepicker` the jquery datepicker widget?

Comment: The listener must only be attached to element when input has focused

Comment: yes, I know, but keep my questions: which kind of listener, click, blur, change? What is the expected behavior of that listener? Which parameters? Or you want to create this datetimepicker when some input receive focus?

Comment: `not yet loaded` - does it mean the element does not exist on page load, but is added with some Javascript later?

Comment: not yet loaded mean that the element does not exist on page loaded but is added with some Javascript later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create this datepicker when some input receive focus

```
$('body').on('focus', '.datepicker', function () {
    $(this).attr("autocomplete", "off").datetimepicker({
        timepicker: false,
        format: 'Y-m-d',
        formatDate: 'Y-m-d'
    })
});
```

It's work for me